# in Java, after declaring a multidimensional array, is it possible to partly fill it with literals?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

After declaring a multidimensional array in Java, is it possible to partly fill?

```
int[][] a = new int[10][5];
a[0][] = {1,1,0,0,0};
a[1][] = {0,0,0,1,1};
```

The rest of the array will be filled later by the code.

Comment: Yes, but it is giving an error. Eran's answer below works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes :

```
a[0] = new int[] {1,1,0,0,0};
a[1] = new int[] {0,0,0,1,1};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use    [`fill(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, int val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method too if you want to fill the array with a specific value.

```
Arrays.fill(a[0], 0, 3, 1); //fill a[0] with 1 from index 0 to 3
```

Comment: `fill()` returns void.

Comment: But still it modify the array it get. Probably I didn't get your point.

Comment: And yet it still returns void, so the assignment `a[0] = Arrays.fill(...)` does not work. It's a syntax error.

Comment: Oh! Thanks I didn't noticed it. Just modified it.